# Kill Process from Command Name

Tags: shell, process, command

In my project i need to write a function that will take the name of a command in parameter, and then will kill the process that is executing this command. I don't know how exactly to go about this problem. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Shell means in linux or windows?

Comment: NO, that's wrong understanding. Shell, doesn't necessarily mean linux. Every OS has a command environment to run command which we call Shell and so every OS has it's own Shell. So, you should be specific about the OS you are using based on which answer depends.

Comment: noted! thank you. Anyways do you have a suggestion to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean linux/unix: to capture the process ID of a command, you can use `pgrep`:

```
pgrep COMMAND
```

This returns the process ID as an integer, which you can then pass to `kill`.

```
kill -9 $(pgrep COMMAND)
```

COMMAND is an extended regex pattern - so `pgrep test` would match commands called `test`, `pgrep *test*` would match `test`, `tester`, `bashtest` etc. You may also have access to `pkill`, which is similar but skips a step by directly killing the process matched.